# Listing files with specific extension inside a directory: how to handle fake duplicates

Tags: java

Hello and thank you for taking some time to read my problem.
Probably the title is a bit unintelligible, so i am about to explain the problem better.

So, the task is to list the files inside a dir with a specific extension.
So far, no problem, it is pretty easy to do that, below there is the fragment of code i used.

```
String[] list = file.list((dir, name) -> {
    if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
for (String f : list) {
    System.out.print(f + "\n");
}
```

The actual results is that inside a directory i've a pdf file which i created and a ppdf file that i created too, to see if the code would've printed only the pdf or the ppdf.
It printed both.
But i only need the pdf one; what can i do?
Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `name.toLowerCase().endsWith("." + ext)`

Answer (score 5):

I guess that the easiest thing that you could do is to analyze if it ends with ".pdf" instead of just "pdf".

Comment: I feel very dumb now that you've pointed that out.. thanks :D ^^"

Answer (score 3):

You could just check that the file ends with `.pdf`:

```
String ext = ".pdf";
String[] list = file.list((dir, name) -> {
    if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```